# Call to undefined method Spatie\Geocoder\Facades\Geocoder::setApiKey()

Tags: php

Here is my code. It gives an error:

> Call to undefined method Spatie\Geocoder\Facades\Geocoder::setApiKey()

```
public function create()
{
        $subcategories = Subcategory::orderBy('subcategory_name', 'asc')->pluck('subcategory_name', 'id');
        $client = new Client();
        $geocoder = new Geocoder($client);

        $Address = $geocoder->setApiKey(config('geocoder.key'));

        $Address = $geocoder->getCoordinatesForAddress('Samberstraat 69, Antwerpen, Belgium');
        $lat = $Address[0]->lat;
        dd($lat);

        return view('companies.create', compact('subcategories'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the api key in the config (config/geocoder.php) then there is no need to set it each time you use the service. It is already set when it's retrieved from the DI. You should change the code to:

```
public function create()
{
    $subcategories = Subcategory::orderBy('subcategory_name', 'asc')->pluck('subcategory_name', 'id');

    $address = Geocoder::getCoordinatesForAddress('Samberstraat 69, Antwerpen, Belgium');

    $lat = $address[0]->lat;

    dd($lat);

    return view('companies.create', compact('subcategories'));
}
```

LE: Did you registered the alias and the service provider in the app config file?

```
// config/app.php
'providers' => [
    '...',
    Spatie\Geocoder\GeocoderServiceProvider::class
];
// config/app.php
'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'Geocoder' => Spatie\Geocoder\Facades\Geocoder::class,
)
```

Comment: Now show this Error : Call to undefined method Spatie\Geocoder\Facades\Geocoder::getCoordinatesForAddress() @Matei Mihai

Comment: Just updated the answer.. make sure you registered the service provider and the facade in the app config file

Comment: Yes i do that @Matei Mihai